# Make Try Catch Faster Python

Tags: python, api, compiler-errors, runtime, try-catch

I am creating a trying to call an api, and setting an except to catch any errors that could happen. However, the program lags on the try part for about a minute. Is there a way to make the code give up on the server and choose the except path in a smaller amount of time?

Edit: Here is the code

```
url = "http://10.10.120.48:8080/api/GetChannelList?pageSize=100&pageIndex=0"
try:
    rsp = requests.get(url)
except:
    #error message
```

Comment: How are you communicating with the servers? Many network communication libraries have an adjustable timeout setting. Show us your code and we'll figure out if yours has one.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for asking questions about specific programming questions. Your question is too broad to be answered. Please read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using the requests module. The line 'rsp = requests.get(url)' is actually making the rest api call. There is by default some delay in that call, execution time is likely to vary depending on multiple variables, without additional information it's pointless to explore them all. What you're more than likely looking for is adjusting the HTTPAdapter for the requests session object you're building.
First, do your imports:

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
```

Then build a Retry object to be used for the max_retries field in an HTTPAdapter object. Note the connect and back_off factor, there are the values you're interested in. Note* This is optional you can simple build the adapter and pass it an int value for max_retries.

```
retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
```

Then instead of making a simple get call you need to instantiate a requests session then mount it. Don't worry about mounting with 'http://' you can change this later if you want I suggest reading through the docs... link below

```
reqObj = requests.Session()
reqObj.mount('http://', adapter)
```

Finally, you can make your get request using the session object you instantiated. 'response' will hold the same data your 'rsp' variable did

```
response = reqObj.get(Url)
```

The entire snippet to copy and paste is below ;). I suggest looking at the docs for requests, they touch on sessions and advanced usage here.  http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry

Url = 'http://CoolApiDomain'

retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
reqObj = requests.Session()
reqObj.mount('http://', adapter)

response = reqObj.get(Url)
```